# Windows could not reconnect all network drives

Tags: windows, network-share, mappeddrive

*OK, before you get all "OFF TO SUPERUSER WITH YOUR ISSUE!", they specifically state in their Help pages: "**NOT about** issues specific to corporate IT support and networks", and since this is a corporate network I'm dealing with and I'm the IT manager/sr.admin, well there you go...and yes I feel silly being unable to figure this out myself, but like TLC I ain't too proud to beg.  Disclaimer done.*

---

### ISSUE

I've been getting this message lately "could not reconnect all network drives" upon a reboot of my Win 8 Pro laptop (example image below):

[image]

### TROUBLESHOOTING

Yet, when I check both the Explorer GUI (clicking the "click here to check the status of your network drives") and the cmd line "net use" commands, the proper drive mappings are there.

I've also checked the registry under `HKEY\CURRENT USER\Network` and find the correct mappings.

I see no events in the application, security, or system event logs to correspond to the "error" message.

It appears to me that nothing is wrong.

**NOTE:**  I do know that the same message will appear when I'm "off the corp network", for instance when I'm booting up my laptop at home.  I get that...but this is when I'm hardwired into the network and have network connectivity (proven via one of the servers able to ping my laptop and run mgmt tools on it before I log in).

### QUESTIONS

So I guess the real questions are:

1. Is this error message valid at some point?  Maybe it is displaying it a split second prior to the drives getting connected for some reason?  Is there a way to troubleshoot it and figure out what it is really squawking about?
2. Barring #1 even being possible, can I simply suppress the message period?  I don't really care about it to be honest, so not seeing it won't cause me any grief.

Comment: Is network discovery off?

Comment: @Colyn1337 - on the domain profile no...private profile yes.

Comment: Just curious, not that I *think* it matters, but are the drives mapped with the FQDN or the short name?

Comment: Are you using non windows dns (such as an IPAM appliance)?

Comment: @MDMarra - there are 5 mapped drives, all using the netbios short name.  They all show mapped fine with no red X, and I can open any of them right away after clicking on the "click here to check the status of your network drives"

Comment: @Colyn1337 - nope, regular Windows DC/DNS/DHCP.

Comment: OFF TO SUPERUaww.

Comment: Also, we get this as well. Windows 7 with Server 2008 DCs/FS's, mapped network drives on login. As it doesn't cause an issue we don't really worry about it. We have the GPO set as MDMarra mentioned below.

Comment: Same here with Win7 and shares on everything from Win2003-Win2012.  Never been a real issue either, but the messages are a might bit annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While MDMarra's suggestion was good and is typically something that should be set via GPO anyway to allow for network scripts, etc. to function properly during login, unfortunately it didn't fix it like I thought.  Consider it a placebo effect for a few days, but the issue returned in force.

But, I did find a Technet community post that did end up fixing it, by suppressing the message and simply not establishing an immediate connection upon login to the mapped location.  The mapped drive is still there though.

So hope this helps others that come along:

In the registry you will need to create a new DWORD value.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\
>
> Set or create a DWORD
>
> RestoreConnection = 0

Then reboot.  Done.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon\Always wait for 
the network at computer startup and logon` configured in your GPO, it's possible that your computer boots and you log in with cached credentials before the NIC is up and has obtained an address. Then, by the time you get around to opening Explorer, you've got an address and your mapped drives are no longer disconnected.

On modern hardware you *shouldn't* need to configure this, but I've seen some terrible NIC drivers out there so better safe than sorry. Although, this typically fixes GPO processing issues not mapped drives, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: That gpo setting isn't pushed out currently, like you said I haven't seen a need to configure this on our network yet.  I will set my local policy setting for this and let it run a few days and see what happens.

Comment: Well, that solved it...at least for me on Windows 8 Pro.  I am upgrading now to 8.1 and will turn off this local setting and see if it happens again, but so far this has definitely fixed the issue.  Thanks man.

Comment: ***nailed it***

Comment: Actually, funny thing is that on the first boot of 8.1 it was back.  But subsequent reboots it is fine.  Could be that the initializing of 8.1 held back the GP processing on first run but who knows.

Comment: GPO may not have applied on the first boot, entirely possible.

Comment: It's back...crap.  Even with this policy applied.  I'm trying to find the various regkeys that correspond with network drive mappings to see if an old mapping/key is messed up.  The frustration is ALL the correct mappings from GPOs are there immediately when you open Computer or click the "click here for status" message.

Answer (score -4):

<del>Remove shortcut from desktop that points to that drive.</del>

Create a bat that makes the connection, and add it to autorun!

```
net use s: \\path\to\drive
```